# Return true if a given PIN number has a character; false otherwise?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a list of PIN numbers =, three of which are listed below:

1. `"12 171H01 003"` should return `True`
2. `"12 371 04 003"` should return `False`
3. `"12 671 C04 029"`

All the PIN numbers have spaces between them. Some have at least one character among them.

If any of the PIN numbers has a character, return true otherwise, return false.

The function below is not working. It returns false regardless whether or not the PIN number passed to it has a character.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
Public Function FoundChar(ByVal strPIN As String) As Boolean

    Dim Pattern As String = "[a-zA-Z]"
    Dim reg As New Regex(Pattern)

    Return reg.IsMatch(strPID)

End Function
```

Comment: They all have characters in them.  I assume that you mean "letter" rather than "character". You could do without the `Regex` and use `strPin.Any(Function(c) Char.IsLetter(c))`.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:

Dim  C = '12 171H01 003'

If  strPin.Any(Function(c) Char.IsLetter(c))????

Comment: No, I mean get rid of all the code in your method and just return the expression I provided.

Comment: From the help: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine:

```
Sub Main
    Console.WriteLine(FoundChar("12 171H01 003")) 'True
    Console.WriteLine(FoundChar("12 371 04 003")) 'False
    Console.WriteLine(FoundChar("12 671 C04 029")) 'True
End Sub

Public Function FoundChar(ByVal strPIN As String) As Boolean

    Dim Pattern As String = "[a-zA-Z]"
    Dim reg As New Regex(Pattern)

    Return reg.IsMatch(strPIN)

End Function
```

The only difference was a typo in your code - you had `strPID` instead of `strPIN`.